# Need to create a button for a link using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a link on the website which says "USE CURRENT LOCATION". I want to change that link to a shape of button. 
ID of the button is btnGeolocation

You can have a look at that link in this page https://order.subway.com/Stores/Find.aspx?pid=1#pg1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your stylesheet! it should work... edit the css to get the shape you want!

```
#divSearchLocation #btnGeolocation{
border: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
border-radius: 100px;
padding: 8px;
background: #e1e1e1;
box-shadow: inset 0px -18px 25px -18px black;}
```

Comment: Can you please let me how can I add hover to button. As you can see on this page https://order.subway.com/Stores/Find.aspx?pid=1&intcmp=ordersubwaycom:owned:order:flavor:fwh-flavor-w5-2017:0:im:0:order-now:mrq:v1&segment_code=0, there is start order CTA when you hover it changes the image, how can I replicate the same on Use Current location button.

Comment: I don't have permission to access that page...

Answer (score 1):

Html for button

```
<a href="#" class="page-button visual-button link">button</a>
```

and css

```
.link{
  text-decoration:none
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.link:hover{
  text-decoration:none;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff; }

.link:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 0 0 #f9b980, 0 2px 0 0px #f9b980;
  background-color: #fc983f; }
  .visual-button:active {
    top: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 0 0px #f9b980, 0 0px 0px 0px #f9b980; }
```

Comment: if you don't want to happen when hover you can just remove hover action

Answer (score 0):

No jquery required here. Use CSS border and background property, you will achieve the result.

Comment: Not able to get it... Can you please elaborate. You can see that page for reference

Answer (score 0):

You can use only CSS to do that, 
Check out this link :
 https://www.freshdesignweb.com/css3-buttons/

I hope this could help you